# How to read and write to console window continuously and logging all the console data to a text file

Tags: vb.net, redirect, console-application

I have a console application which I need to run like `c:\abc.exe -showhidden`.

Once executed, it asks the user to select option A (for example number 32|64) and after the user selection it shows some more options (from 1 to 100) on the console, say option B and on the basis of option B selection, it performs some operations on the console continuously.

I tried using the below code for providing the input:

```vb
    Dim StartInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo
    StartInfo.FileName = "C:\abc.exe"
    StartInfo.Arguments = " -showhidden"
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
    StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
    StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
     CMDprocess.StartInfo = StartInfo
     CMDprocess.Start()
     CMDProcess.StandardInput.AutoFlush = True  
        Dim sw As System.IO.StreamWriter = CMDprocess.StandardInput
            sw.Writeline("32") ' option A
            sw.WriteLine("86") ' option B
            CMDProcess.StandardInput.Flush()
```

Issues I have:

1. The console hangs after `sw.Writeline("32")` and I am unable to provide option B, i.e., `sw.WriteLine("86")`.
2. How to log the output (after selecting option B) to a text file.

Comment: Do you have `CMDProcess.WaitForExit()` after the last line? If you do, remove it. You also don't need `CMDProcess.StandardInput.AutoFlush` and `CMDProcess.StandardInput.Flush()`. The other *side* of course has `dim input = Console.ReadLine()`. Maybe add `Console.WriteLine($"Your input is {input}")` in the Console app and `dim stdOut = CMDProcess.StandardOutput.ReadLine()` to acknowledge the results in the other app.

Comment: I forgot to mention: you may want to get hold of the Process and the StreamWriter objects, subscribe to the `Process.Exited` event (requires `Process.EnableRaisingEvents = true`) and dispose of the StreamWriter and the Process objects when the `Exited` event is raised. Of couse, in case you need to keep track of the Console app status and maybe write something else to `stdin`.

Comment: Thanks Jimi. But can you help me with an example. Also I don't have CMDProcess.WaitForExit().